# call method in kotlin from java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using a library written in **kotlin** and I need to access methods on it.

This is the signature of kotlin method:

```
 public final fun connect(userId: kotlin.String, onFailure: (kotlin.String) -> kotlin.Unit, onSuccess: (UserEntity) -> kotlin.Unit): kotlin.Unit {}
```

How can i call this method from java?

**EDIT**

I already tried this:

```
new Function1<String, Unit>() {
                        @Override
                        public Unit invoke(String s) {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Could you give some more context? Is this a method on a class, or a top-level function? Why did you declare it public? It tought in kotlin everything is public by default? I guess it will be difficult to call this from Java because you use Lambdas without defining a functional interface

Comment: @GhostCat: What is helpful is constructive feedback: Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not

Comment: @BastianVoigt please check my edit, but I do not know if that is right or not

Comment: As said: it doesn't help to *guess* what the "class file" signature of that kotlin function is. Turn to the class file, and use javap, and you get told about the exact types. But Bastian is correct, you should add *where* your kotlin fun lives.

Comment: What's wrong with your Function1 try? Any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Try next code:

```
FileKt.connect("", s -> { 
            //do something when Failure
            return null;
        },
        o -> {
            //do something when Success
            return null;
        });
```

where `FileKt` - name of the file where `connect` function is defined.